# Temperature sensor DS18B20 always reads 85

Tags: pcb, stm32

I'm using a temperature sensor [DS18B20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) with STM32F103 Bluepill, but this sensor always gives me 85°C which is the power-on reset value of the temperature register.

I'm so confused because it worked as well while I was doing my wiring on a breadboard. I don't know why it doesn't work on a PCB, I did the same wiring as I did on a breadboard.

Does it require any additional setting while using that sensor on a PCB with an external power supply like a Li-Po battery? I have put a 4.7K resistor too. I have read some posts regarding this problem but it doesn't give me solutions. For the data pin, I'm using PB5 on my STM32F103.

I don't think it caused by the code because it worked well on a breadboard, this is my whole code:

```
int DSPIN = PB5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  double temp = TempRead();
  temp  = temp * 0.0625; // conversion accuracy is 0.0625 / LSB
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" °C");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}
 
boolean DS18B20_Init() {
  pinMode(DSPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(DSPIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(750); //480-960
  digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  pinMode(DSPIN, INPUT);
  int t = 0;
  while (digitalRead(DSPIN)) {
    t++;
    if (t > 60) return false;
    delayMicroseconds(1);
  }
  t = 480 - t;
  pinMode(DSPIN, OUTPUT);
  delayMicroseconds(t);
  digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  return true;
}
 
void DS18B20_Write(byte data) {
  pinMode(DSPIN, OUTPUT);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(DSPIN, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    if (data & 1)
      digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
    else 
      digitalWrite(DSPIN, LOW);
    data >>= 1;
    delayMicroseconds(50);
    digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  }
}
 
byte DS18B20_Read() {
  pinMode(DSPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  byte data = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(DSPIN, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
    pinMode(DSPIN, INPUT);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    data >>= 1;
    if (digitalRead(DSPIN)) 
      data |= 0x80;
    delayMicroseconds(55);
    pinMode(DSPIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(DSPIN, HIGH);
  }
  return data;
}
 
int TempRead() {
  if (!DS18B20_Init()) 
    return 0;
  DS18B20_Write (0xCC); // Send skip ROM command
  DS18B20_Write (0x44); // Send reading start conversion command
  if (!DS18B20_Init()) 
    return 0;
  DS18B20_Write (0xCC); // Send skip ROM command
  DS18B20_Write (0xBE); // Read the register, a total of nine bytes, the first two bytes are the conversion value
  int temp = DS18B20_Read (); // Low byte
  temp |= DS18B20_Read () << 8; // High byte
  return temp;
}
```

My PCB schematic:

[image]

Any suggestions or bits of help would be great.

Comment: If the same code and the same sensor work on a breadboard but not on your PCB then there is some difference between your breadboard circuit and your PCB circuit that is causing the problem. You need to start comparing voltages at different points on both to find the difference, you can't debug this by staring at the code.

Comment: yeah like I said that I don't think it caused by the code, thanks for your suggestion. I have overcome this issue

Comment: Can you then please share the solution. It would help others.

Comment: @Lazureus I just changed my old DS18B20 with the new one, everything is ok after that. I have tested it on 5 other device